# Which parts of the Eclipse Platform, if any, adhere to ISO 9241?

Tags: standards

Has the Eclipse Platform implemented with any concepts of ISO-9241 in mind? If so, which parts?

Is the *menu functionality* provided by the **Eclipse Rich Client Platform** adhering to *ISO 9241-14:1997. Ergonomic requirements for office work with visual display terminals (VDTs) -- Part 14: **Menu dialogues***, if used standardly, as implicated by the providers?

Comment: There are some nice summaries of the standard on our friend Wikipedia, including depreciated sub-sections. Do a quick scan over there. Some are harder to test than others without special equipment (pixel defects spring to mind) but most are easy to verify with a working knowledge of the application.

Comment: The question is broad. ISO 9241 has approximately 37 parts. A more focused question about ask about Eclipse's adherence to one part, e.g., Part 14 - Menu Dialogues. Also 'Eclipse Platform' is ambiguous. It could mean any one of the 13+ Eclipse packages available on the Eclipse Foundation's Downloads page or it could mean the Eclipse Rich Client Platform that is the starting point for creating rich client's with Eclipse

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify what I'm actually asking for.

Answer (score 1):

In the 2007 Master thesis [Exploring Usability Guidelines for Rich Internet Applications  Eclipse](http://lup.lub.lu.se/luur/download?func=downloadFile&recordOId=1336270&fileOId=1646468) is mentioned as a tool used, but never in compliance with ISO 9241. The same goes for the Eclipse wiki, where [Rich Client Platform](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Rich_Client_Platform) is a big part. Nothing on ISO 9241 is mentioned on these pages. If you [search for "ISO"](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Special%3aSearch?search=ISO&go=Go) you find reference to other standards such as 8807, [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) (8-bit single-byte coded graphic character sets used in web pages), 3166, 704, 9000 and more standards - but not 9241.

To conclude, it's a fair assumption that Eclipse Rich Client Platform is not complaint with ISO-9241. If it where, it would have been mentioned.